# Problem in empty select - remove all options from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have select with id="select_test", how to delete all options inside but select stay on page, so I can load again some new options ? ( I get answer how to load, but I cannot empty, I tried like `$('#select_test').empty();`

and

```
$('#select_test').find('option').remove();
```

but it doesn't work ). Can someone say what I did wrong ?

Comment: both should work. is the id unique? is your code in the jquery .ready()? Do you get any errors?

Comment: [That does work.](http://jsfiddle.net/eZ5ps/) You should describe the situation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/PkPST/2/).
Or try this code:

```js
$("#emptySelect").click(function() {
  $('#select_test').empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_test" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Low</option>
  <option>Medium</option>
  <option>High</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="emptySelect" value="empty options" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_test')[0].length = 0;
```